# High TTFB on using cloudfront that access to an image URL compare acess image in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have no idea why the TTFB is so high when using cloudfront to access the image based on url compare to using cloudfront access the image from s3 bucket. 
FYI, the path of `k/300/` is just for resizing the image from the url after the `300/`

Below are the two image with two different link.

https://d2m21v07ktfjkm.cloudfront.net/k/300/https://cdn-doublewootenterp.netdna-ssl.com/content/images/thumbs/0079731_davinua-blush_480.jpeg

[image: cloudfront access image from url]

https://d2m21v07ktfjkm.cloudfront.net/k/300/https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ootdfixproducts/products/0079731_davinua-blush_480.jpg

[image: cloudfront access image from s3 bucket url]

Anyone know how to reduce the TTFB time when cloudfront access the image from url not from s3 bucket?

Comment: It feels like there are other things happening here, that you are overlooking or otherwise not mentioning (Or that I am missing.)  The resource with S3 in the URL appears to actually be coming from an Apache web server, not S3.  `Server: Apache`
`X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.16`, just like the other one. If CloudFront is fetching both of these from the same Apache server (a resizer?) then the question is why the resizer is slower to fetch from one or the other, and seems entirely unrelated to CloudFront.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot, it coming from an Apache web server, not S3 is because when create cloudfront contribution i set my origin to my domain name. My domain server is using apache. But i still don't understand why getting image from S3 and directly from an image url will have different of TTFB time. It is because of it need to depend on where the image is host?

Comment: Test the TTFB by connecting directly to the origin server.  If S3 is still faster, the issue is related to the performance of the system handling the other image URL.